# Self contained login using HTML and/or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

I am looking at making an idle game that stores data server side(instead of cookies) and would like a simple way (no mysql or php preferably) to register and login using html5 and/or javascript. I am VERY new to programming and therefore have no example to show sorry. any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why did you tag it with JAVA?

Comment: You are contradicting. `stores data server side(instead of cookies)` and `no mysql or php preferably`???

Comment: Java is to JavaScript as ham is to hamburger.

Comment: @PraveenKumar The set of server side languages and databases is greater than 2. However, it looks to me that OP wants to avoid any effort whatsoever rather than having a specific aversion to these two platforms.

Comment: I am sorry for any confusion that i caused and any contradictions that i made. it was not intentional i really am just trying to learn and teach my self, thank you for clearing these points up for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Disclaimer:** I know it is stupid or a sin to answer this kind of question, but it is okay for an absolute beginner.

You have a lot of contradictory statements. First you said you wanna store it in the server side, but not PHP or MySQL (which is basically one of server side programs).

You are confusing Java and JavaScript. This is like equating Hamburger and Hamburg or Ham? Whatever. Java is **not** JavaScript. Please understand.

A solution for you is `localStorage` and using it, you can store and retrieve data for the particular session, the more or less almost same way how a server session works. You can use the following snippet to check if the user is logged in:

```
if (typeof Storage !== "undefined") {
  if (localStorage.getItem("user") != null)
    // User is logged in
  else
    // Redirect to login.
}
```

Please have a look about how to work with `localStorage`. This is ideal for Games, as they might need to go in and around pages and share information between them.

Comment: Thank you very much Praveen Kumar I just needed a place to start which you gave me and now ill figure the rest out! :)

Comment: @Akmedrah I believed this in you. That's why I answered you the question and you proved it too. All the best. `:)`

Comment: So i looked into this and it was helpful for another project that i am working on, but corect me if i am wrong this would store the data on the clients computer?
If that is the case then i was not clear enough in my question which was already pointed out (sorry about that) i am looking to store the logins in the same root directory as the game files. i know this is not secure but i am not worried about security. i just don't want people to lose progress/login info if they reset their browser info. 
If you know of anything that Might do this, or even what language it should be in it would be

Comment: Greatly appreciated.
Don't worry if its a pain in the butt to answer, I don't want to waste any of your time! :)